# Java Array returns Null

Tags: java, arraylist

So when I use this to pick a String of random events it returns a null:

```
public static List<String> pickNRandom(List<String> lst, int n) {
    List<String> copy = new LinkedList<String>(lst);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);
    return copy.subList(0, n);
}

static List<String> randomP;
public List<String> items(){
    List<String> teamList = new LinkedList<String>();
    teamList.add("team1");
    teamList.add("team2");
    teamList.add("team3");
    teamList.add("team4");
    teamList.add("team5");
    teamList.add("team6");
    List<String> randomPicks = pickNRandom(teamList, 3);
    randomPicks = randomP;
    return randomPicks;
}

public static void Store() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int people = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    List<String> itemsIn = randomP;
    System.out.println("People in store: "+people + "\nItems in store: "+itemsIn);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Store();

}
```

Why is it returning null and what can I do to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, it's not at all clear to me what you are trying to do here!

Comment: Why are you assigning `randomPicks = randomP;` right before you return `randomPicks`?

Comment: items() method is not even called, npe happens at sysout

Comment: I set them equal in order to get my picks on a different variable

Comment: Should I remove that?

Comment: I think you may have meant to do `randomP = randomPicks;`, but really, the `randomP` variable isn't needed at all.

Comment: What do you expect? you never assign anything to `randomP` so it value is always `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line   `List<String> itemsIn = randomP;` you assign list that was not initialized its default value is `null`. I think that's how your line should look like: `List<String> itemsIn = items();` remember to change method `items()` to static.

Comment: Thanks this makes much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is clear, but not question (it can have different solutions)... I've added small changes.

```
public static List<String> pickNRandom(List<String> lst, int n) {
    List<String> copy = new LinkedList<String>(lst);
    Collections.shuffle(copy);
    return copy.subList(0, n);
}

public static List<String> items(){
    List<String> teamList = new LinkedList<String>();
    teamList.add("team1");
    teamList.add("team2");
    teamList.add("team3");
    teamList.add("team4");
    teamList.add("team5");
    teamList.add("team6");
    return pickNRandom(teamList, 3);
}

public static void Store() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int people = rand.nextInt(50) + 1;
    List<String> itemsIn = items();
    System.out.println("People in store: "+people + "\nItems in store: "+itemsIn);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Store();
}
```

> People in store: 10
>
> Items in store: [team6, team2, team3]

---

In your code `randomP` was useless (never initialized, never filled in)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initiated `List<String> randomP` at any point.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return null. You immediately overwrite what the function returns with an uninitialized variable here:

```
randomPicks = randomP;
```

It's not clear why you have that... but don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

**randomP** is declared but not initialized, `items()` is never called, same as `pickNRandom`

so you can initialize the list (but this doesnt mean that it will be populated...)

```
 static List<String> randomP = new ArrayList<>();
```

you will get an empty list instead of null

> People in store: 12
>
> Items in store: []